# Need form inputs to append php variables onto all href

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Basically I need a form with different filters (checkboxes and dropdowns) to add the appropriate php variables and values onto the end of any internal link, and stay checked and selected after page submit.

I am at a complete loss as to how to do this without adding an if statement onto every href...

Is there a global way to tack something on to the end of any link that is clicked?

Comment: There may be a better solution to your problem. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: something similar to amazon or ebay where you have a sidebar that filters results.

Comment: like have a dropdown menu with price intervals, and whatever is selected will append ?price="X-Y" onto any internal link that is clicked.  i have the filtering functions handled already, i just need the variables to be passed.